# Is there an efficient way to iterate through an avro schema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, schema, avro

I would like to be able to iterate through and access the 'name' field values of an avro schema but have not been able to find an efficient way of doing so without getting extra values due to the particular way avro expects its schema data.

I can recursively iterate through it as though it were a js object; however, I end up with certain fields I did not want being included in my results.

For example, in the below code the only value I want to get back is 'foobar' however I also get 'Foo' which I do not want as that is the name of an array of objects rather than a single value.

```
{
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Foo",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "foobar",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
}
```

The current function I am using looks like this:

```
  iterateAvro = (target) => {
    let result = [];
    Object.entries(target).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        if (val === null){
          return null
        }
        if (typeof val === 'object'){
          result = result.concat(this.iterateAvro(val));
        } else {
          if(key === 'name'){
            result.push(val) 
          }
        }
    })
    return result
  }
```

I am new to avro (and coding in general) and do not know if there is an avro specific way of doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing in your function is:

1. Convert a JavaScript object into an array of key/value pairs.
2. Iterating through the pairs and:
   a. If the `value` is `null` do nothing.
   b. If the `value` is an object, apply this logic to it using recursion.
   c. If the `key` is `name` push the value to an array called `result` accessed through a `Clojure`.

Your function is grabbing any `value` whose key is `name`. That is why both `foobar` and `Foo` are returned.

Looking at [Apache Avro's documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#schema_complex) I see that inside the `fields` key, there is a list with multiple `field` objects, each of which must have a `name` key.

So, assuming that you would like to get the values of all the `field names` you could do something like this:

```
// JSON object gotten directly from Apache Avro's documentation.
var avroRecord = {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "LongList",
  "aliases": ["LinkedLongs"],                      // old name for this
  "fields" : [
    {"name": "value", "type": "long"},             // each element has a long
    {"name": "next", "type": ["null", "LongList"]} // optional next element
  ]
}

function getFieldsNames(record) {
  return avroRecord.fields.map((field) => {
    return field.name;
  });
}

console.log(getFieldsNames(avroRecord))
// [ 'value', 'next' ]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! @guzmonne That was very helpful :)

Comment: @Jess222, you are welcome. Please mark the question as answered if it helped you.

Comment: I would if I could @guzmonne, but it won't let me yet as I have 'less than 15 reputation'.